# how to add billing and shipping addrrss seprately

Tags: customer-account

i want to add customer billing and shipping address programtically via php code below i code i found to add address:

```
$_custom_address = array (
    'firstname' => 'Branko',
    'lastname' => 'Ajzele',
    'street' => array (
        '0' => 'Sample address part1',
        '1' => 'Sample address part2',
    ),
    'city' => 'Osijek',
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => '',
    'postcode' => '31000',
    'country_id' => 'HR', /* Croatia */
    'telephone' => '0038531555444',
);
$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
//$customAddress = new Mage_Customer_Model_Address();
$customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
try {
    $customAddress->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

but this add same billing and shipping address how to insert different values for billing and shipping

Answer (score 0):

```
 - define two separate array like `$_custom_address_shipping` and `$_custom_address_billing`

    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

                if (!$customer->getId()) {
                    $this->_fault('customer_not_exists');
                }

                $_custom_address_shipping= Mage::getModel('customer/address');
$_custom_address_shipping->setData($_custom_address)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('0')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
try {
    $_custom_address_shipping->save();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}
```

// twice you need to run the save customer address

```
 $_custom_address_shipping= Mage::getModel('customer/address');
```

`$_custom_address_shipping->setData($_custom_address)
             ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
             ->setIsDefaultBilling('0')
             ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
             ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');`

```
try {
     $_custom_address_shipping->save(); } 
catch (Exception $ex) {
     //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage()); }
```

Comment: Did you tried this and it worked?

Comment: Yes! Are you having any issues with this Code? Your code is perfect, I just RE-USED your code for solution. If you want to create Shipping and billing address separately, just try to run the process twice! First time with `setIsDefaultBilling('1')
setIsDefaultShipping('0')`. Second time with `setIsDefaultBilling('0')
setIsDefaultShipping('1')`.